# Matplotlib: Saving chart does not work correctly unless I use plt.show() after it

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create and save multiple charts using Matplotlib:

```
# Perfect Numbers Functions
# -------------------------
def getdivisors(n):
    "Get all divisors of a number."
    divisors = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return divisors

def isperfect(divisors):
    "Sums the divisors of a number and checks if it is equal to the number."
    n = divisors.pop() # Grab the top number
    total = sum(divisors) # Sum all the divisors
    if n == total:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Matplot!
# --------
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# iterate over some numbers
for i in range(2, 10):
    # get all divisors of the number
    divisors = getdivisors(i)

    # convert divisors to strings so they work as x labels
    xlabels = [str(x) for x in divisors]

    # create bar chart
    bars = plt.bar(xlabels, divisors)

    # change last bar to red if it's a perfect number
    if isperfect(divisors):
        bars[-1].set_color('r')

    # save chart
    filename = "%i.png" % i
    plt.savefig(filename)

    # show chart (must come after save)
    # plt.show()
```

For some reason, the charts do not save correctly (they seem more generic) unless I run `plt.show()` after each chart. However, that means I have to view and close each chart as the script runs.

**How can I make matplotlib save the charts exactly as they appear in `plt.show()` without having to run `plt.show()` after each chart?**

I am sure I am making a simple mistake here, but I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: You do not have to show the chart to save it. Your problem here is just that you plot all data into the same figure. So best close the figure at the end of the loop.  `plt.close()`

Comment: Perfect, thank you!